# In Hyperledger Composer, what does a "Participant" represents?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In a B2B blockchain network, is "Participant" meant to represent the business or the person that acts on behalf of the business (e.g. an employee) or both?
In most of the examples that I have seen, "Participant" seems to represent the business. But once you start thinking about security and Participant-Identity mapping, "Participant" as a person makes more sense.

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 1):

Participant: Participants represent the organizations or people who take part in the digital business network. Participants are defined in the business network model.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/glossary.html

And: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participantsandidentities.html

Comment: Thanks Dan! I am familiar with the definition of Participant and Participant-Identity mapping. What I am finding is that there is a difference between "Participant" from the business perspective and "Participant" from the application/technical perspective, or the participants that have an identity associated with them and the participants that don't. Do you see a need to make that distinction at the composer level?

Answer (score 1):

In Hyperledger Composer, your 'active' Participant (or 'a' participant) may operate at a transactional level,  in that it uses an identity to perform actions (adding assets, submitting transaction(s) that update those assets, query execution etc) - and needs at least one identity associated with it, to execute such transactions. At an Hyperledger Composer level, that Participant can be a person, or (if so implemented by the author's use case) it can be represented as a participant entity eg. Payroll Administrator (and still have an identity or identities mapped to it). Think for example also, of needing access control - who can see what at a Participant level? In Hyperledger Composer, one participant can have multiple identities - but only one is submitted (as an identity signature) with a transaction at a time.

Now from a 'business' perspective (irrespective to any Composer context) a business (organisation) can also 'participate' in a business network as a 'party' (so, a complex network of companies, working together to accomplish certain goals and have a business relationship with each other, narrowed down to specific business flows). To implement this on a blockchain, the parties will want to reduce this down to a level where identities and participants (and all the other elements of the modeled network) are defined in the network they join. So really, its just a question of context, and I think you'll now see what modeling and using a Participant in Hyperledger Composer means, and the outer context.